# Multiple AVPlayers ducking?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avaudiosession

I have a relatively simple setup involving 1 AVPlayer looping some ambient audio in the background and a second player playing a shorter sound at certain points.

What I've observed is that when the short sound is played, I hear the ambient clip cut out for about a second while there is a staticy pop.  It then proceeds to continue playing while the short sound is played at the same time.  This only happens on device - it's not noticeable on the sim, which seems to point to a potential performance issue.

I can't quite figure out why the first AVPlayer has this blip.  Here is the code for the ambient player:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kAmbientTrack ofType:@"mp3"];
_ambientPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[self.ambientPlayer play];
```

It's slightly more complex, as I also listen for a notification when it ends and the restart it, but this issue happens even during the initial play before any looping occurs.

So while that is going in the background, I play another clip like so:

```
  self.announcementPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[myObject audioPathUrl]];
  [self.announcementPlayer play];
```

So nothing too unique there - just two AVPlayers playing.

The only other piece of interest is how I set up the audio session when the app launches.

```
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];
```

I'm doing this to allow the user to play music from other apps in the background.

I think my code is pretty straight forward, and really have no idea why I would be getting this blip.

---

I fixed this somewhat by changing the audio players to be AVAudioPlayers.  That resolved the popping in most cases.  However, I still get the ducking.  Specifically, if I play an AVAudioPlayer and, while it's still playing, I start to load an AVPlayer, it cuts off the AVAudioPlayer for about a second.  Here's what I'm talking about:

```
  [myAVAudioPlayer play];
  AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[self.currentExercise videoPathUrl]];
```

The addition of that second line causes the first second or so of myAVAudioPlayer to be silent.